# How to compile a F# project without buying Visual Studio

Tags: f#, monodevelop, visual-studio-express

I have found this very cool project written in F#: https://github.com/fholm/IronJS

OSS is very nice, but i need an assembly. I would compile it by my self, but it seems that there is no free IDE to open a F# project (.fsproj). I don't have Visual Studio and there is no express version for F#.

I have found this site http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-in-monodevelop.aspx but it seems cross-platform doesn't include Windows.

This Monodevelop add-in doesn't work: http://functional-variations.net/addin/

Have someone already successfully used F# on Windows without Visual Studio?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734525/getting-started-with-f/734536#734536

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can downlaod the VS2010 shell from here http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=8E5AA7B6-8436-43F0-B778-00C3BCA733D3&displaylang=en

Then install the F# compiler etc from here http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=effc5bc4-c3df-4172-ad1c-bc62935861c5.

Then you'll have full IDE support for F# with intellisense, projects etc. Doesn't cost a penny and works like a charm!

GJ

Comment: But it doesn't work with Visual C# Express or am I doing something wrong? He is still reporting ".fsproj is not supported"

Comment: Don't think so no, but you should be able to install the shell side by side with C# express, to get F# support.

Comment: Ok, i had to reinstall (uninstall, repair doesn't work) the F# package. I installed that first (already before I've asked that question here), that was the fault.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/) - it has build-in F# support. The only thing required is [F# compiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=effc5bc4-c3df-4172-ad1c-bc62935861c5&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 5):

You can download a F# standalone version (to get the compiler) from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=effc5bc4-c3df-4172-ad1c-bc62935861c5&displaylang=en). It seems that it also integrates with Visual Studio Shell, which can be downloaded separately (follow the link at the download page). But I must confess I never tried this ...

Comment: I've used the VS Shell for programming in D before; I would imagine that F#'s support for it is very good. It'll likely also allow you to use F# project files and solutions containing them.

Comment: @shambulator - yep, I use F# + VS2010 shell and support is solid: 1) F# project template with .fs, .fsi, and .fsx awareness, 2) intellisense, 3) debugger, 4) FSI integration, ...

Answer (score 3):

[Download from here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=effc5bc4-c3df-4172-ad1c-bc62935861c5&displaylang=en)

> This CTP release includes the F#
>   compiler and tools, as well as
>   optional Visual Studio integration for
>   F# development.

Meaning, the package includes the F# compiler, you don't need Visual Studio integration to compile a project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a college student, you can get VS 2010 professional version for free through [DreamSpark](http://www.dreamspark.com/) program.

VS 2010 Pro. has full support for F#.